# Is there a best practice, or typical way to do AJAX updating for data on a custom admin screen or post.php?

Tags: custom-post-types, ajax, customization

I have a custom post type that deploys custom meta boxes on the **post.php** screen.

```
add_meta_box('myMetaBox', __( 'My Box' ),array( $this,'echoMetaBox'),'MyBox', 'side', 'high');
```

I want to display simple information in the metabox via AJAX. Is there a typical approach to do this, or an API, or a way to piggy back on the browser auto save that is done by WordPress every few seconds? I can do this myself by registering my own endpoint, with my own JS. I was just wondering if there is a **TYPICAL** way of doing this or a best practice approach? I'm not talking about enqueuing a JS script. The answer might very well be: "no, there is no typical or best practice approach". I'm specifically interested in getting my data when the browser auto-saves the post content.

Comment: Probably a good use case for the hearbeat api https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/heartbeat-api/

Comment: I knew in the back of my mind this existed! Jacob, your comment is the right answer.